# Is there a nonchronic disease with similar effects to lungs like those of emphysema?

Tags: lungs, disease, respiratory-system, pulmonology

Can damage to the alveolar walls or reduction in the surface for gaseous exchange be reversible or can a non chronic disease cause these? If yes can you please name a condition in which these things happen in alveoli?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, damage to the alveolar walls or the reduction in surface area for gaseous exchange can be reversible. Additionally, acute (non-chronic) conditions can cause these circumstances. For example, in salt or freshwater drowning<sup>1</sup> victims,  wash out and destroy surfactant, disrupt the alveolar-capillary membrane, and increase its permeability.<sup>2,3,4</sup>

In the case of drowning from freshwater or saltwater, some patients with mild lung injury will require supplemental (non-mechanical) oxygen for 6-48 hours.<sup>5</sup> Other patients may need invasive (intubation with mechanical support ventilation) or non-invasive (mechanical support ventilation like CPAP or BiPAP).<sup>5</sup> The time required to regenerate surfactant is approximately 48 hours,<sup>5</sup> and therefore, that is likely how long they will require mechanical ventilatory support to reverse the injury.<sup>5</sup>

Another condition you may want to research that has a similar, reversible cause to the collapse of alveoli is **atelectasis**.<sup>6</sup> Additionally, you can research acute spontaneous **pneumothorax** as another condition that is related to your description.<sup>7</sup>

**References**

1. Van Beeck EF, Branche CM, Szpilman D, Modell JH, Bierens JJ. A new definition of drowning: towards documentation and prevention of a global public health problem. Bull World Health Organ. 2005;83(11):853-856.
2. Olshaker JS. Near drowning. Emerg Med Clin North Am. 1992;10(2):339-350.
3. DeNicola LK, Falk JL, Swanson ME, Gayle MO, Kissoon N. Submersion injuries in children and adults. Crit Care Clin. 1997;13(3):477-502. doi:10.1016/s0749-0704(05)70325-0
4. Bierens JJ, Knape JT, Gelissen HP. Drowning. Curr Opin Crit Care. 2002;8(6):578-586. doi:10.1097/00075198-200212000-00016
5. Chandy D, Richards D. Drowning (submersion injuries). UpToDate. https://www.uptodate.com/contents/drowning-submersion-injuries?search=drowning&source=search_result&selectedTitle=1~78&usage_type=default&display_rank=1. January 23, 2023. Accessed March 9, 2023.
6. Muller, NL, Fraser, et al. Radiologic diagnosis of diseases of the chest, Saunders, Philadelphia 2001.
7. Gupta D, Hansell A, Nichols T, Duong T, Ayres JG, Strachan D. Epidemiology of pneumothorax in England. Thorax. 2000;55(8):666-671. doi:10.1136/thorax.55.8.666